# JqueryMobile asp.net authentication

Tags: jquery, authentication, mobile-website

How can I accomplish this in JqueryMobile

I have a an aspx file which takes userName and password . Using the web service call in .ajax , I am athenticating the user. Now I would like the user to be sent to a different page , example auth.aspx. How can I accmplish this ...?? I also want to make sure auth.aspx file is not accessed without login. I know to acomplish this with plain asp.net technologies. But can't figure out how to do the same using JQueryMobile. Can anyone help me with this ...???

Thanks in advance...!!!!

Comment: Is $.ajax making a call to a web service or a page method?

Comment: its making a call to webservice...!!!

Comment: Are you storing a session on the server?

Comment: I would like to ...but How can I do so...??? Jquery is more of client side right...???

Comment: You are correct, Jquery is client side. However, if I understand your question correctly, you need to manage the authentication on the server. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're working on an ASP.NET site, your solution I believe lies on the server.

First you need to decorate the authentication webservice method with this attribute:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
public result Authenticate()
{
}
```

Now, when you successfully validate the user, set a Session variable to logged in:

```
Session["IsLogged"] = true;
```

You get the webservice result in the browser and it's successful, redirect using window.location = "auth.aspx";

On the auth.aspx page, just check if the session variable exists and is set to true. If it's not there or not true, then Response.Redirect back to the login page...

**EDITS**

Notifying the user is very straight forward... 
The methodology for this has varying levels of complexity, to start simple:
put a span html tag on your login page, add an id attribute to the html tag

```
<span id="login_success"></span>
```

Then use jQuery to update the text in that span after you return from the authentication webservice.

```
$('#login_success').text('You have successfully logged in!');
```

Comment: Great….it worked. However I got stuck with another problem. Once authenticated I need to display authentication success in a label. I am using all html controls. How can I achieve this ..??? The client side Jquery part needs to informed from server side….right ..??? But how ..???

Again thanks for the help.